# Why can I not save any files with Blender 2.8

Tags: blend-files

When I try to save files I just get message
Can not open file C:...\testi.blend@ for writing. No such file or directory.
What went wrong?

Comment: Seems like a rights issue. Try opening blender as admin.

Comment: No such file usually means that some directory along the path either doesn't exist, or is write protected against you. To check this, in the file manager, right click on the  directory and select properties. If the read-only flag is checked, or the 'security' tab shows you don't have read permission you will get this error.

Comment: I have seen similar problems (with other software) if the path contains odd characters or even spaces. IF this is the case this should be considered to be a bug and therefore be reported.

Comment: Opening any non system level software as admin or root should never be the solution.